# php get sub array from an array

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

here is an array and I want to extract "category_input" as sub array. This sub array contains "cat_id" and "post-titles". Then I will want to insert the posts into WordPress DB under each category. is. cat_20 will have posts named as post-in-cat-20 and so on.

```
Array
(
    [post_type] => post
    [post_status] => publish
    [content_texarea] => 
    [category_input] => Array
        (
            [0] => cat_20
            [1] => post-in-cat-20
            [2] => post-in-cat-20
            [3] => post-in-cat-20
            [4] => cat_19
            [5] => post-in-cat-19
            [6] => post-in-cat-19
            [7] => post-in-cat-19
            [8] => post-in-cat-19
            [9] => cat_2
            [10] => post-in-cat-2
            [11] => post-in-cat-2
            [12] => post-in-cat-2
        )

)
```

Expected Results

extracted array will be as

```
    [category_input] => Array
    (
        [0] => cat_20
        [1] => post-in-cat-20
        [2] => post-in-cat-20
        [3] => post-in-cat-20
        [4] => cat_19
        [5] => post-in-cat-19
        [6] => post-in-cat-19
        [7] => post-in-cat-19
        [8] => post-in-cat-19
        [9] => cat_2
        [10] => post-in-cat-2
        [11] => post-in-cat-2
        [12] => post-in-cat-2
    )
```

Then, I will need to make caegory and posts array to use in wp query

```
    [category_input] => Array
    (
        [cat_20] => Array
            [1] => post-in-cat-20
            [2] => post-in-cat-20
            [3] => post-in-cat-20
        [cat_19] => Array
            [5] => post-in-cat-19
            [6] => post-in-cat-19
            [7] => post-in-cat-19
            [8] => post-in-cat-19
        [cat_2] => Array
            [10] => post-in-cat-2
            [11] => post-in-cat-2
            [12] => post-in-cat-2
    )
```

Comment: Please add the expected result

Comment: Which one is your desire output?? second one??

Comment: yes second one result

Comment: Checkout the answer

Answer (score 2):

As you want to update the portion of your array- take a look at the given parts.

The array from the main array by `$main_arr[category_input];`

```
foreach($category_input as $val){
    $part = explode('_', $val);
    if(isset($part[0]) && $part[0] == 'cat'){
        $out_arr[$val] = array();
        $key = $val;
    }else{
        $out_arr[$key][] = $val;
    }
}
```

Look at the complete example: https://3v4l.org/JI9U7

Now you can put the `$out_arr` again to the `$main_arr`.

Comment: Let me test it Brother!

Comment: Frayne! I think I made you confused. First I will want the to get a sub array of index "category_input".

Comment: By using the `$main_arr[category_input]` you can get the subarray

Comment: Thankyou very much @Frayne Konok. It is working perfect. Thanks. I have tested it and getting the desired results.